# C# DirectoryEntry.Invoke Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. One or more input parameters are invalid

Tags: active-directory, change-password

```
 usr.Invoke("ChangePassword", new object[] { strCurrentPassword, strPassword});
```

This api works in some environment of Active Directory and fails in some with following exception

Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.One or more input parameters are invalid.

Comment: Try using `UserPrincipal.ChangePassword` instead: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.authenticableprincipal.changepassword(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I am aware of UserPrincipal.ChangePassword but my question is why the DirectoryEntry.Invoke for changePassword behaves inconsistent in different environment.

Comment: Well without more of your code it's impossible to tell if it is that or a bug in your code.

Comment: Can you describe the differences between the environments?

Comment: The "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.One or more input parameters are invalid" is mainly observed mainly if the new password you are trying to apply is violating the Active Directory PASSWORD POLICY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently Microsoft rolled out a new update https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/ms16-101
which does not allow to do changePassword other than administrator with NONSSL configuration. It requires minimum Kerberos or SSL to do changePassword. They removed the support for NTLM which was the default mechanism earlier used.

Answer (score 1):

Even the following is true
The "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.One or more input parameters are invalid" is mainly observed mainly if the new password you are trying to apply is violating the Active Directory PASSWORD POLICY.